# Conditional probability and the binomial distribution

Tags: probability

> Let an unbiased die be cast at random seven independent times. Compute the conditional probability that each side appears at least once given that side 1 appears exactly twice.

We have $P[(\text{Each side appears} \geq 1) \mid (\text{Side 1 appears exactly  exactly twice})] = \dfrac{P[(\text{Each side appears} \geq 1) \cap (\text{Side 1 appears exactly twice})]}{P[\text{Side 1 appears exactly twice}]}.$

For the numerator, if side 1 appears exactly twice, then the other 5 sides must appear exactly once. The probability of side 1 appearing exactly twice and the other 5 sides appearing exactly once is $(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{1}{6})^5$. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways of having side 1 appear exactly twice, and there are $5!$ ways the other 5 sides can appear exactly once.

Hence the numerator is  $\binom{7}{2}\cdot5!\cdot(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{1}{6})^5.$

For the denominator, the 1 appearing exactly once has the probability $(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{5}{6})^5$. Considering that the 1's can be rolled in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways, the denominator is $\binom{7}{2}(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{5}{6})^5$.

When I divide the numerator by the denominator, I get $120\cdot\frac{1}{5^7} = \frac{24}{5^6},$ but the author has $\frac{24}{625} = \frac{24}{5^4}$, so somewhere I have two too many factors of 5.

Comment: I haven't looked at your method yet, but if you are simply looking for a way to get the answer, i think you could ignore the two rolls of 1 and look at the other 5 rolls.  The first could be any of 5 numbers, so that probability is $\frac{5}{5}$ (Five in denominator because we are assured none of these 5 rolls can be a 1 due to the conditions).  The next roll has 4 possibilities, the next has 3, etc.  So you get $\frac{5*4*3*2*1}{5*5*5*5*5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numerator and denominator are both correct.  You can cancel $7\choose 2$ and $\left( \frac16 \right)^7$ top and bottom, leaving $\frac{5!}{5^5}=\frac{4!}{5^4}$

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just made a little mistake near the end of your calculation: instead of $120 \cdot \frac1{5^7}$, it should be $120 \cdot \frac1{5^5}$.